I knew it was true in the core of my being
From Merriam-Webster,  I read this example sentence from the being entry:

I knew it was true in the core of my being.

What's the meaning of the expression, "in the core of my being"?
Is the sentence similar to "I knew it was true instinctively."?

Source? Context is necessary to determine meaning, even if it appears straightforward. And if the meaning is easily discerned, then the question lacks effort and research.

Yes; it probably means instinctively, and probably also means the speaker is very certain about the thing being true.
